# How to read multi-level JSON files?

Tags: json, r, rjson

I have a multi-level JSON file like so:

```
{
  "key1":1,
  "key2":"a"
}

{
  "key1":2,
  "key2":"b"
}
```

My goal is to convert this file into a `data frame` with two columns and two rows like so:

```
ml_df
  key1 key2
1    1    a
2    2    b
```

At the moment, I have:

```
library(rjson)
ml_json <- fromJSON(file = "multi_level.json")
ml_df_fail <- as.data.frame(ml_json)
```

The problem is that `ml_df_fail` has only one row with two columns like so:

```
ml_df_fail
  key1 key2
1    1    a
```

How to read multi-level JSON files in R?

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON("multi_level.json", flatten = TRUE)` maybe?

Comment: This leads to a parsening error: `Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you generated that JSON file?

Shouldn't it rather look something like:

```
[
  {
    "key1":1,
    "key2":"a"
  },

  {
    "key1":2,
    "key2":"b"
  }
]
```

For this, I can use `jsonlite::fromJSON("test.json")`

Comment: I forgot about the square brackets.